Poorly-acted 90s–2000s low-budget sci-fi movie with ill-fated desert miners and a man-eating monster
I'm looking to identify this movie that was really low-budget; I saw it sometime in 2023. I remember there was a group of miners that had gone either into a cave or mine because there was supposed to be gold, or maybe valuable gems. But this monster came out and ate everyone once they started to mine.
The monster had a weird name, and I think the name of the monster was included in the name of the movie, but I am not 100% sure. I only saw the first 10 minutes, and then we turned it off because the acting was so bad. 
I think it must have been made after the 80s, probably in the 90s or 2000s. It was based in the desert. I believe it was an American movie. I am mainly trying to remember the name of the monster in the movie. 

It's not Tremors is it?

Can you describe the appearance of the monster? Also, was there just one monster, or several?

I think there was more than just one like a herd of them. I dont remember much about what they look like. I think they could walk on two legs. They were protecting whatever people were trying to mine.

Cowboys vs Dinosaurs is also a match for the described plot

It was Night of the Tommyknockers.

When miners blast for gold in the 1870's, they accidentally release ancient creatures known as Tommyknockers. The Town of Deer Creek, Nevada is soon under siege with only a handful of survivors held up in the local saloon.

Movie came out in 2022 and is a Western horror movie.
I was way far off in my description of the movie, but this was definitely the movie I was thinking of. Thank y'all for the help.




Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.

released in 2022 ???  you indicated it was released a long time ago... implying over a decade ago, so 2022 release date seems incorrect

I used to think this movie was somehow related to Stephen King's novel 'The Tommyknockers' ('De Gloed' in Dutch), but it's not, other than drawing a parallel to the traditional use. Traditionally, tommyknockers are supposedly the ghosts of dead miners, warning or scaring miners. This movie seems to stay a bit closer to that idea, adding some Hollywood.

Possibly Tremors 4: The Legend Begins. This film starts with a silver mine in the American desert. It's set in the old West time period, if that's more help. It was a direct to video movie (hence bad acting) released in 2004.
Relevant to the question: the monsters were called the graboids.

Prim East Coast dandy Hiram Gummer arrives in the fictional town of Rejection, Nevada, to investigate a series of strange deaths at the silver mine he owns. Receiving help from local innkeeper Christine Lord and miner Juan Pedilla, Gummer finds out that gigantic killer worm-like graboids that can burrow underground are responsible for the miners' deaths. Hiram decides to recruit expert gunslinger Black Hand Kelly to save the day. However, the graboids grow larger, and the people of Rejection decide to kill them before they reach Carson City.


No I don't think so the name of the monster was different and the movie wasn't set in a past time period it was present day. As in when it was made i believe. I dont remember see the actual monster it was like it grabbed them and there was blood splatter indicating they were dead. If it helps to note I vaguely remember a hot blonde character. I think the knew it was there but decided to risk it for the brisket.  They did not own the mine. I think they were given warning that something was killing in the mines .

I remembered this movie while watching skinwalker ranch because skinwalker gave a similar vibe as the name of the monster.

I dont think the monsters were burrowed in ground they were just living in the mines like it was there home/territory.
